# Android sdk alert in main class

Tags: android, sdk, dialog, alert

I have a Problem with the android alert box

I imported `"import android.app.AlertDialog;"` and now I wanted to show an alert in the main class:

```
public void main() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("hallo").setTitle("!");
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
    this.init();
}
```

The `"init"` function sets the playground.
But Unfortunally nothing happens, and also the init woun't execute.
If I remove the Alert, the init executes perfectly.

Comment: How does this function get called? When "nothing happens", are there any errors in the log?

Comment: what did you do in init()?

Comment: I'm pretty sure its not the init();. I commented it out and it didn't fix the problem. On the other side if I delete the Alert-part, the init(); works fine.

Comment: In the log I found the following warning:
IInputConnectionWrapper: reportFullscreenMode on inactive InputConnection